# ImageFailed with GridView

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I have a problem with GridView and multiple items. Each of the item has image in it, source is online image, bound to property, like this:

```
    <GridView x:Name="gridView" Width="710" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="306" Height="210">
            <Border Background="White" Opacity="0.1"/>
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Width="190" Height="100" Margin="0,50,0,0" ImageFailed="ImageFailed" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Image paths are like this:

- www.example.com/images/1.png
- www.example.com/images/2.png
- www.example.com/images/3.png
- and so on...

If some image not exist, for example www.example.com/images/29.png, I use the event ImageFailed, which change the source of the image to image that is located in my project (default image). Code in this event:

```
private void ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;            
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/default.png"));
}
```

And this is working just fine, the default image is shown in the items that don't have images. But, when I scroll down the gridview, and then return to the beginning, images are messed up. Some items that had their images, now have the default image. Again when I scroll the gridview, and then return, again random changes with images.

Is this some cache problem? What could be the problem here? Or is there any better way of setting the default image source?

Comment: I suggest you to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms or https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading. This will help you implement image loading and error image handling.

Comment: I am working in UWP, not Xamarin...

Comment: This library can work in , Library to load images quickly & easily on Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms and Windows (UWP, WinRT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of your problem could be virtualization, i.e. reuse of item containers. When you replace a failed image by a fallback image in your ImageFailed handler, you are effectively replacing the Binding by a fixed value, so that the item container will later always show only the fallback image.

You may instead implement the `ImageFailed` handler in the view model, so that replacing the image with a fallback image won't break the Binding.

Add another property, e.g. `Image` to your item class

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    private BitmapImage image;
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            if (image == null)
            {
                image = new BitmapImage();
                image.ImageFailed += (s, e) =>
                    image.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/default.png");
                image.UriSource = new Uri(ImagePath);
            }

            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

and change the Binding to this:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding Image}"/> // no ImageFailed handler here
```

Comment: Thanx, this solved my problem. I just slightly modified the code to:

    if (image == null)
    {
     image = new BitmapImage();
     image.ImageFailed += (s, e) =>
     image.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/default_channel_icon.png");
    }

    image.UriSource = new Uri(ImagePath);

    return image;